# Laplace transform method to solve two coupled differential equations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, laplace-transform

I was reading QUANTUM OPTICS for BEGINNERS by Z FICEK, in his discussion of the Jaynes-Cummings model he use Laplace transform method to solve two coupled differential equations (8.9) as shown in the picture. I tried the method but i never arrive to the same result.

> Thus, we have obtained two coupled differential equations that can be written in the form:
> $$\begin{cases} \dot{C}_{1n}(t)=-in\omega_0C_{1n}(t)+\frac12g\sqrt{n}C_{2n}(t) \\ \dot{C}_{2n}(t)=-in\omega_0C_{2n}(t)-\frac12g\sqrt{n}C_{1n}(t) \\ \end{cases} \tag{8.9}$$
> The set of equations $(8.9)$ can be solved for arbitrary initial conditions using, for example, the Laplace transform method. The solution for the amplitude $C_{2n}(t)$ is given by $$C_{2n}(t)  =\frac12e^{-in\omega_0t}\{[iC_{2n}(0)-C_{1n}(0)]e^{\frac12 i\Omega t} + [iC_{2n}(0)+C_{1n}(0)]e^{-\frac12 i\Omega t}\} \tag{(8.10)} $$,
> where $\Omega = g\sqrt{n}$ is the Rabi frequency.

Comment: Write the problem in matrix form and diagonalize the antihermitian coefficient matrix. Show all your work. What, exactly is the problem? You are asking for a freshman-year matrix diagonalization?

Comment: @Frobenius Why you introduce Z ? should i apply laplas on Z ?

Comment: No, I mean (8.9) is a trivial matrix equation, leading you to @Frobenius ' eigenstate. Clean up your system before obsessing on Laplace.

Comment: @Frobenius Many thanks to you. I tried your method and got the same result. I don't know why the author suggested Laplace transform,  which made me confused.